# Priority Queue implemented as singly linked failing to update pointer refrence on insert

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Question Edited: How can I insert into my linked list while keeping pointer references as arguments? My updated code is as follows:

Note: I have a copy of the queue which was used in inserting a given node into the correct spot however I'm not seeing anyway to update the original queue as there no way to link the previous nodes.

Resolved: Working priority queue (FIFO) - Needs cleaning

```c++
#define QUEUE_HEAD_INDICATOR 0.0

namespace
{
    pq* create_node(float priority = 0, const string & text = "")
    {
        pq* q = new pq;
        q->priority = priority;
        q->text = text;
        q->next = nullptr;
        return q;
    }
}

pq* init_priority_queue() {
    return create_node(QUEUE_HEAD_INDICATOR);
}


void insert(pq* &queue, string text, float priority) {
    if (!queue) return;

    pq* prev = queue;
    pq* cursor = queue->next;
    int offset = 0;

    if(prev->priority == 0.0 && prev->text == "") {
        prev->priority = priority;
        prev->text = text;
        return;
    }
    if(!cursor) {
        if(prev->priority > priority) {
            pq* node = create_node(priority, text);
            node->next = prev;
            prev = node;
        } else {
            pq* node = create_node(priority, text);
            prev->next = node;
        }
    } else {
        while(cursor && cursor->priority < priority) {
            prev = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            offset++;
        }
        pq* node = create_node(priority, text);
        if(offset == 0) {
            if(cursor->priority == (int)node->priority) {
                node->next = prev->next;
                prev->next = node;
                queue = prev;
            } else {
                node->next = prev;
                prev = node;
                queue = prev;
            }
        } else if(!cursor) {
            prev->next = node;
        } else {
            node->next = prev->next;
            prev->next = node;
        }
        return;
    }
}


string remove(pq* &queue) {
    pq* prev = queue;
    pq* cursor = queue->next;

    if(!queue->next) {
        string text = queue->text;
        prev = NULL;
        return text;
    }

    while(cursor->next) {
        prev = cursor;
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    prev->next = NULL;
    string text = cursor->text;
    return text;
}
```

Here is what the struct looks like

```c++
struct pq {
    float priority;
    string text;
    pq* next;
};
```

Comment: Why are you writing C code in C++?

Comment: @Yashasn I don't see why it would matter as it complies fine but fails when inserting in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to make an assumption here: `queue` is a reference to a pointer to the head node of a linked list. This seems a reasonable assumption because of the way it is used in the `if(queue->next == NULL)` case.

The following code will overwrite the pointer to the head node, and subsequently every other node, leaking it.

```
while(queue->next && queue->next->key < priority) {
    queue = queue->next; // bam! previous node leaked back at the caller
}
```

You could use a copy of the head node, but... There are much better ways to handle this.

My recommendation is to not pass pointer to a root node. Pass a pointer to the pointer to it. This handles the head case by making the head look exactly like every other node and eliminates most of the code. Since we're always keeping a pointer to the previous node's `next` we have easy access to the insertion point for a new node and the next node.

You cannot do this trick with a reference because a reference cannot be reassigned.

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// my best guess at what pq looks like
struct pq
{
    pq* next;
    std::string text;
    float key;
};

void insert(pq ** queue, // cannot reseat ref, so pointer required
            const std::string &text, // ref eliminates copy.
                                     // const because we don't want to change
            float priority) {
    while((*queue) && // search while more queues
            (*queue)->key < priority) // and priority is low
    {
        queue = &(*queue)->next;
    }
    *queue = new pq{*queue, // if queue is null, end of list, if not inserted in middle
                    text, 
                    priority}; 
}

// Demo
int main()
{
    pq * queue = NULL;

    insert(&queue, "c", 5);
    insert(&queue, "a", 1);
    insert(&queue, "b", 2.5);
    insert(&queue, "e", 10);
    insert(&queue, "d", 7.5);

    // print and clean-up.
    while (queue)
    {
        std::cout << queue->text << std::endl;
        pq * temp = queue; // temp so we don't lose queue
        queue = queue->next;
        delete temp; // release node
    }
}
```

Comment: @smerlin This helped tremendously! I didn't know you couldn't resign references. So if I wanted to keep same queue structure, I'd have to do something like create a new function that would save each pointer reference before queue = queue->next

Comment: @usuer4581301 ^

Comment: @Garrett What I described above should be adaptable to your queue structure without requiring a helper function, but I may be missing something in your specific case. Consider asking a new question so you can provide a fuller example of what you currently have.

Comment: I updated the main question. In this specific case, I actually have to use a pointer reference. I was able to isolate my problem creating a copy of the linked list and inserting the new node in correct position. Now my original queue is unmodified however I still haven't solved getting the rest of the list in the right position without overwriting the previous nodes in queue.

Comment: You do not want to create a new queue. You're trapped into having a special case for the head node. That sucks. You never want special cases even if you can't avoid it and have to grit your teeth and bear it. I'll have to come back to this later.

Comment: I've solved this issue. The code needs cleaning up but I will post for anyone who might be interested in passing pointer references. From what I understand so far, you should only overwrite queue in edge cases otherwise you're losing previous nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment `queue = new_node` assigns the argument of the insert function, but not the pointer in the middle of the linked list (which is the `next` member variable of the previous element).

```
    pq* qp = new pq;
    insert(qp, "0.1", 0.1f);
    // qp -> 0.1
    insert(qp, "0.3", 0.3f);
    // qp -> 0.1 -> 0.3
    insert(qp, "0.2", 0.2f);
    // qp -> 0.2 -> 0.3
    // qp now points to the 0.2 element, leaving the 0.1 element inaccessible
```

Also your function never compares the priority of the first element with the priority of the element to be inserted for queues with a length > 1.
Your while loop only compares the priority of the element to be inserted to the priorities of the elements beyond the first element.